# Get number of cores and core IDs in foreach

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach, cpu-cores

Is there a way to get number of cores and their IDs utilized in these two foreach loops. I need to compare CPU utilization for both cases. I have execution times from System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch, but I also need info on number of cores. Here is my code for those loops:

```
//foreach encryption

var foreachWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
                       
foreach (KeyValuePair<long, MyClient> klijent in clients)
{
    if (klijent.Value.id != obj.id)
    {
        MyClient tmp = new MyClient();
                                
        long id = klijent.Value.id;
        byte[] pubKey = Convert.FromBase64String(klijent.Value.keyString.ToString());
        byte[] IV = Convert.FromBase64String(klijent.Value.IVString.ToString());
        byte[] secretMessage = serverDK.Encrypt(pubKey, dekriptovanaSaUserInfo);
        tmp.id = id;
        tmp.pubKey = pubKey;
        tmp.buffer = klijent.Value.buffer;
        tmp.IV = IV;
        tmp.handle = klijent.Value.handle;
        tmp.client = klijent.Value.client;
        tmp.data = klijent.Value.data;
        tmp.IVString = klijent.Value.IVString;
        tmp.keyString = klijent.Value.keyString;
        tmp.stream = klijent.Value.stream;
        Send(Poruka(secretMessage), tmp);
        tmp.data.Clear();
        tmp.handle.Set();
    }
}

foreachWatch.Stop();
                        

//parallel foreach

var parallelWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
                        
Parallel.ForEach(clients, klijent =>
{
    if (klijent.Value.id != obj.id)
    {
        MyClient tmp = new MyClient();
        long id = klijent.Value.id;
        byte[] pubKey = Convert.FromBase64String(klijent.Value.keyString.ToString());
        byte[] IV = Convert.FromBase64String(klijent.Value.IVString.ToString());
        byte[] secretMessage = serverDK.Encrypt(pubKey, dekriptovanaSaUserInfo);
        tmp.id = id;
        tmp.pubKey = pubKey;
        tmp.buffer = klijent.Value.buffer;
        tmp.IV = IV;
        tmp.handle = klijent.Value.handle;
        tmp.client = klijent.Value.client;
        tmp.data = klijent.Value.data;
        tmp.IVString = klijent.Value.IVString;
        tmp.keyString = klijent.Value.keyString;
        tmp.stream = klijent.Value.stream;
        Send(Poruka(secretMessage), tmp);
        tmp.data.Clear();
        tmp.handle.Set();
    }
});

parallelWatch.Stop();
```

Can't seem to find solution for this specific issue. Mostly solutions are for determining the number of CPU cores using Environment.ProcessorCount...

Comment: Use [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) instead of Stopwatch.

Comment: Why the `Environment.ProcessorCount` isn't sufficient for getting the number of cores? Also please consider editing the question and improving the formatting of the code, paying attention to the indentation, and reducing the whitespace to avoid the appearance of the horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias well doesn't that just gives me the number of cores available. I need to see utilization. On which specific core/cores were these foreach loops running. Can that be achieved with Environment.ProcessorCount?

Comment: The `Environment.ProcessorCount` only tells the number of CPU cores. The specific core that runs each iteration is a too low-level information. One iteration might start on one core, and finish on another core. There is no guaranteed 1:1 relationship between iterations and cores. It is also possible that one iteration will run for the most part on no core at all. The `Send(Poruka(secretMessage), tmp)` is most likely a blocking I/O operation. These operations use other hardware devices, like the network card, not the CPU. Why do you want this information?

Comment: I would like to see if there is a difference between the number of cores utilized by foreach and Parallel.ForEach

Comment: [Analyze CPU usage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/cpu-usage?view=vs-2022)